# EndOfStream cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, list, class, methods

I have to create a program for my class and I am almost finished. I have this code linked to a class called PersonEntry. I am attempting to find out why my EndOfStream is not working. It says that it cannot be used as a method

```
namespace Jason_Todd___IS_204___HW11CH9_7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string selectedName = "";
        List<PersonEntry> nameList = new List<PersonEntry>();

    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // gotta load the names from this list. Because, you know, I need to get a grade.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile;
                inputFile = File.OpenText("Personlist.txt");

                string inRecord;

                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream())  // This is where my error occurs.
                {
                    inRecord = inputFile.ReadLine();
                    string[] tokens = inRecord.Split(',');

                    PersonEntry friendObj = new PersonEntry(tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2]);

                    listBox1.Items.Add(friendObj.Name);


                    nameList.Add(friendObj);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show("Exception in try/catch. ");
            }
        }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedName = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            PersonInfoForm myPerInfoForm = new PersonInfoForm();
            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Size = new Size(270, 75);
            label1.Location = new Point(10, 10);

            foreach (PersonEntry PersonEntry in nameList)
            {
                if (PersonEntry.Name == selectedName)
                {
                    label1.Text += "Name: " + PersonEntry.Name + "\n" +
                                   "Email: " + PersonEntry.Email + "\n" +
                                   "Phone number: " + PersonEntry.PhoneNum;
                }
            }

            myPerInfoForm.Controls.Add(label1);
            myPerInfoForm.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`EndOfStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.endofstream(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property, not a method. Just remove the `()` and it will compile.

Answer (score 1):

> [`.EndOfStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.endofstream(v=vs.110).aspx) is a read only property of `StreamReader` class. Gets a
>   value that indicates whether the current stream position is at the end
>   of the stream.

So `()` is not needed to access the value of the property. the statement will looks like the following:

```
 while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)  // This line will not show error now
 {
     // your stuff here       
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I have just one more problem. The names of the people that are on my Personlist.txt file are not showing up on my listbox. Do have any idea of what the reasoning behind that could be? i have my file saved in the right area.

Comment: are you getting any error or exception?hope that  `PersonEntry`  class having a constructor that accepts 3 arguments. is it possible to attach `PersonEntry` class tot eh question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't respond to other people's comments so I'm answering your ListBox question here.

ListBoxes hold objects not strings. When you add an item to your listBox do this `listBox1.Items.Add(friendObj);`

Then you have two options.

1) set `listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"`

2) in your Friend class override the ToString() method and make it return the name like this

```
public override ToString()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

By default ListBoxes call ToString() on the objects you add to them to determine what text to display in the UI unless you explicitly set the DisplayMember property for the ListBox.